# Displaying all nested models with a specific attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I show only account.organizations with 'primary' = true in the database on my /accounts/ page?  Here is what I am trying now:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :organizations
    has_one :primary_organization,
        :class_name => 'Organization',
        :conditions => ['primary = ?', true]

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations

end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :account

    has_many :locations
    has_one :primary_location,
        :class_name => 'Location',
        :conditions => ['primary = ?', true]

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations

end
```

The Organizations table has a 'primary' column that takes a boolean entry.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @accounts = account.organizations.where(:primary => true).all
    end

end
```

And lastly the index view:

```
<h1>Account List</h1>
    <table>
    <% for account in @accounts %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= link_to account.organizations.name if   
                         account.organizations.name %></td> 
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

I am currently getting this error:

```
NameError in AccountsController#index

undefined local variable or method `account' for #<AccountsController:0x1e160b0>
Rails.root: C:/Documents and Settings/Corey Quillen/My    
Documents/rails_projects/shop_manager

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:4:in `index'
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems.  Your first issue is that you never find the account in your accounts controller. Thats why you get the exception you have.  You need to first load the account and then get its organizations.  It looks like you are on rails 3 so you may want to declare a scope for the primary organizations.

```
scope :primary, where(:primary => true)
```

If the above scope is in the Organization class you can say this:

```
@accounts = Account.find(params[:id]).oranizations.primary
```

Comment: I added the scope but @accounts = Account.find(params[:id]).organizations.primary does not seem to work in my index action.  Why do I need to include (params[:id])?  There is no id in the url because I am trying to show a list of all primary organizations via the http://localhost:3000/accounts url.

Comment: do you want to show all primary organizations for any account?  If so, then just use Organization.primary.all

Comment: No, each account only has one primary organization.  How do I show them all accross all accounts?

Comment: I fixed the problem with the following scope: scope :primary, joins(:organizations).where('organizations.primary_organization = ?', true).  I had to change the 'primary' column name to 'primary_organization' because 'primary' is a reserved keyword in SQLite.